# How to specify an optional final argument with \newcommand?

Tags: macros, package-writing

I'm writing my first package, and I'm trying to work out how to create a new command with an optional final argument. In this instance, if an argument is omitted, it defaults to blank. This is problematic because it assumes that the two arguments passed in this case are `#2` and `#3`.

```
\newcommand{\sfsx}[3][]{\wrapper{#1}{#2}{#3}}
```

Unfortunately, I would like it the other way around, where if only two arguments are given, they are assumed to be `#1` and `#2`. Is there a simple way to do this that doesn't invoke other packages?

(`\wrapper` in this case is just another command that takes on various forms depending on package options).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the new [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package, which is built on top of LaTeX3. With this package you can specify arbitrary combinations of mandatory and optional arguments. This case would be as easy as

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \sfsx { m m o } { \wrapper{#1}{#2}{#3} }
```

If you want to have your own default value, use `O{value}` instead of `o`.

Comment: That works pretty well, with the breaking change that the optional argument loses its formatting. Consider the following: `\newcommand{\wrapper}[3]{\ensuremath{\mathrm{\uppercase{#1}}_{#2#3}}}`: running `\sfsx{c}{2}{v}` will produce the expected behaviour for the first two characters but the third will be set in normal sized roman rather than subscript italic.

Comment: @RichardTerrett: `[v]` :-)

Comment: If you want the final argument in a TeX group (`{...}`), you could use the `G` or `g` argument specification.

Answer (score 9):

This can't be done using `\newcommand` directly. One way is to read the first mandatory arguments, store them in a temporary macro and then call another macro which has only one optional argument and reads the other ones from the temporary macro. An easier way would be to use the `xparse` package which allows for several optional arguments at any position (see Andrey's answer).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sfsx}[2]{%
    \def\sfsx@args{{#1}{#2}}%
    \sfsx@
}
\newcommand{\sfsx@}[1][]{%
    \expandafter\wrapper\sfsx@args{#1}%
}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\wrapper}[3]{%
    I got (#1), (#2) and (#3).
}

\begin{document}

\sfsx{A}{B}

\sfsx{A}{B}[C]

\end{document}
```

This can be made a little more efficient if you use the internal `\@testopt` macro directly which is used by LaTeX to test for the optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sfsx}[2]{%
    \@testopt{\sfsx@{#1}{#2}}{}%
}
\def\sfsx@#1#2[#3]{%
    \wrapper{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\wrapper}[3]{%
    I got (#1), (#2) and (#3).
}

\begin{document}

\sfsx{A}{B}

\sfsx{A}{B}[C]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of the empty brace group after `\@testopt` you can write `{xyz}`, and `xyz` will be the default value for the optional argument.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response. As I'm not well versed in the answer syntax, I'm further investigating `xparse`, as whilst it does introduce a dependency, it also seems the most _parsimonious_ method. (:P)