# Can I define a command with optional argument coming after the mandatory ones?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

Is it possible to define new commands having the following form:

```
\command{<marg>}[<oarg>]
```

I have seen commands of this form in the `fontspec` package. But not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes you can, but it is generally not well advised.

Comment: `fontspec` uses a trailing optional argument for commands that should go in the preamble; in general, a trailing optional argument after mandatory ones is not really recommended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify an optional final argument with \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/how-to-specify-an-optional-final-argument-with-newcommand)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take.

The easiest approach is to use `xparse`

Then you can define a command as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{ mO{a} }{#2 \rightarrow #1}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

$\mycommand{A}$ vs $\mycommand{A}[b]$

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can use `\def` and `\@ifnextchar[` to create your own command with trailing optional argument.  But this will be rife with problems.  For example, any `[` following such a macro, regardless of intervening white space, will be picked up.
`xparse` very nicely avoids this by not allowing white space between the last mandatory argument and a trailing optional argument.

I would recommend the `xparse` approach.  However, for the sake of completeness, I will show you at least one way to do this via `\def` and `\@ifnextchar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\mycommand{\my@command}
\def\my@command#1{%%
  \@ifnextchar[%]
  {\@my@command{#1}}{\@my@command{#1}[a]}}
\def\@my@command#1[#2]{#2 \rightarrow #1}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mycommand{A}$ vs $\mycommand{A}[b]$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The package `ltxcmds` provides `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace`

Comment: why `\def\my@command#1` and not `\newcommand*\my@command[1]` ?

Comment: @cgnieder no particular reason.  It seems that there are any number of ways to go about this.  I'm not sure if there's is a preferred or recommended approach.

Comment: Since this is LaTeX personally I'd use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`. I'd also add `\newcommand\@my@command{}` before `\def\@my@command#1[#2]` (this way no macros are accidentally redefined).

Comment: Thanks, both of the solutions work fine. But I think I won't use the second one until some appropriate digging into *The Companion*. :-)

Answer (score 7):

I've used a package by the name of `xargs` (non-disclaimer: just a satisfied user) that seems like a perfect fit here - in particular, the command `\newcommandx`:

```
\newcommandx{\command}[argcount][arg, arg=default]{#1(#2)}
```

`\newcommandx` works just like `\newcommand`, except that the second optional argument is not the default value for the command's first argument (making it optional); instead, it is a comma-separated list of (numbered) arguments that are to be optional. A default value for an argument can be specified by following a number with `=` and the desired default; if not given, the default is blank. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{xargs}
\newcommandx{\mycommand}[2][2=a]{#2 \rightarrow #1}

\begin{document}

$\mycommand{A}$ vs $\mycommand{A}[b]$

\end{document}
```

Here's a command I've actually used, for typesetting derivatives in Leibniz notation:

```
\newcommandx{\dd}[4][1, 2=\mathrm{d}, 4]{\ensuremath{\frac{#2^{#4}#1}{#2#3^{#4}}}}
```

- `\dd x`

  [image: d/dx]
- `\dd[y]x`

  [image: dy/dx]
- `\dd[][\partial]x`

  [image: ∂/∂x]
- `\dd x[2]`

  [image: d²/dx²]
- `\dd[y][\Delta]{x}[2]`

  [image: Δ²y/Δx²]

Comment: Thanks, I'll put it in my reading list of package docs. And good implementation!